# How to send resume data from a form to server using JavaScript in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how to get data from a form with an array from several modules in js?

I need to create a resume. If necessary, the user can add work experience and education. There may be several. And I need to get data from all modules in an array

```
// Сбор данных из модулей опыта работы
$('.work-experience-module').each(function () {
    let workExperience = {
        companyName: $(this).find('input[name="company"]').val(),
        position: $(this).find('input[name="position"]').val(),
        responsibilities: $(this).find('input[name="responsibilities"]').val(),
        workExperienceStartDate: $(this).find('input[name="workExperienceStartDate"]').val(),
        workExperienceEndDate: $(this).find('input[name="workExperienceEndDate"]').val()
    };
    data.WorkExperiences.push(workExperience);
});

// Сбор данных из модулей образования
$('.education-module').each(function () {
    let education = {
        InstitutionName: $(this).find('input[name="educationInstitution"]').val(),
        Degree: $(this).find('input[name="educationDegree"]').val(),
        GraduationDate: $(this).find('input[name="educationGraduationDate"]').val()
    };
    data.Educations.push(education);
});
```

Comment: What's your controller code? Could you share more code about your view ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a hidden text field between form tags and submit it to an endpoint that will consume data.